# Mongo DB throws error when trying to run mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB and set up the data path using `dbpath`. When I am trying to run `mongo.exe` file I am getting the following error.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15-17-g0941b8e
connecting to: test
2017-11-19T09:09:11.726+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017    after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2017-11-19T09:09:11.729+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Are you starting the server (mongod.exe) first?

Comment: I used mongod.exe to set the data path and used mongo.exe to run

Comment: Mongod.exe is the server. Mongo.exe is a client.

Comment: Yea i started mongo.exe first

Comment: You mean mongod.exe, not mongo.exe, right? Are you getting output from it to indicate that it's running?

Comment: My bad:( i didnt set the data path what mongod.exe was looking. Now i am able to run mongo.exe. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try running  'mongod.exe'  from the cmd line in c:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.0/bin and then run mongo.exe once mongod is running.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer and tell him to do the same thing (run mongod)?

Comment: I think you should read again. I am telling him to launch the server in the cmd line, and then run mongo.exe as he has done.

Comment: My bad, I apparently somehow missed that on every reading. I improved the legibility of your answer and upvoted.